# CakePHP: content type header for cached views

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.3

In CakePHP I have a rss view that is requested on `http://example.com/file.rss`. Because of `Router::parseExtensions('rss')` the contents are correctly handled as xml/rss.

Now I'm using `$this->cacheAction` to cache the request. Everything works fine: rss contents are generated and the cache file is created after the first request.

But the following problem occurs: the first request returns a header `Content-type: application/rss+xml` (which is correct). The second request (which is the result of the cached view) returns a totally different header `Content-type: text/html`. But why? How can I make sure to always get the rss header?

I'm using the latest version of CakePHP 2.3.

I already tried to set the header in the rss layout file `default.ctp` by adding

```
// ...
?><!--nocache--><?php
header('Content-type: application/rss+xml');
?><!--/nocache--><?php
// ...
```

and similar code snippets, but without success. The response header is still the html content type.

Comment: One thing I figured out is, that only the `Content-type` header is overwritten in a cached file. When setting other headers within the nocache tags (see example above) they will also be available in cached views. Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: New update (CakePHP 2.3.0 stable) arrived, but still the same behavior...